# How to use multiple #select blocks in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a list of records like:

```
transactions = Transaction.all
```

And I have the following instance methods `@currency, @geo, @industry`. I want to select records which has the following criteria:

- Select all transactions that has field `currency` which equals to `@currency` unless `@currency` is nil and in this case we'll ignore the condition (currency would mean all currencies when it's nil)
- Select all transactions that has field `geo` which equals to `@geo` unless `@geo` is nil.
- Select all transactions that has field `industry` which equals to `@industry` unless `@industry` is nil.

I tried multiple `#select` but with no luck something like:

```
transactions.select{ |i| (i.currency == @currency) unless @currency.nil? }.
        .select{ |i| (i.geo == @geo) unless @geo.nil? }.
        .select{ |i| (i.industry == @industry) unless @industry.nil? }
```

Comment: Wouldn't something like `Transaction.where(currency: @currency, geo: @geo, industry: @industry)`  with maybe `unless [@currency, @geo, @industry].compact.empty?` be sufficient?

Comment: @wpp how would I use it with an array rather than SQL. And how would I apply each query if it exist and not if they all exist. In the case `unless [@currency, @geo, @industry].compact.empty?` it mean it will run unless all values are empty but in my case I want to check each if empty or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transactions.select do |t|
  (@currency.nil? || t.currency == @currency) &&
  (@geo.nil? || t.geo == @geo)  &&
  (@industry.nil? || t.industry == @industry)
end
```

this should do the job.

Or, if you are into dynamics:

```
[:currency, :geo, :industry].all? do |field|
   (ivar = instance_variable_get("@#{field}")).nil? || t.send(field) == ivar
end
```

Comment: `instance_variable_get("#{field}")` is invalid, use `instance_variable_get("@#{field}")`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your example is the `unless @currency.nil?` will return `nil` (which is falsey) if `@currency` is `nil`, which is the opposite of what you intended.

You should use `||` instead:

```
transactions.select{ |i| (i.currency == @currency) || @currency.nil? }.
        select{ |i| (i.geo == @geo) || @geo.nil? }.
        select{ |i| (i.industry == @industry) || @industry.nil? }
```

In this case, if `@currency` is `nil`, the first condition will return `true`, and all elements will pass the `select` box to the next one...

Another option would be to run the `select` block *only* is the parameter is not `nil`. In this case, you'd like to break the line into separate blocks:

```
transactions.select!{ |i| (i.currency == @currency) } unless @currency.nil?
transactions.select!{ |i| (i.geo == @geo) } unless @geo.nil?
transactions.select!{ |i| (i.industry == @industry) } unless @industry.nil?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AR/SQL instead of Ruby processing when possible:

```
transactions.where(currency: @currency, geo: @geo, industry: @industry)
```

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help, but in my case I want to use this in an array. I made transactions example for illustration, I just want to use `select` or `map` to do the job, how would I do that if the values are not nil?

Comment: if `@currency` is nil, then the whole expression is nil, so I don't think this works. Also inline `if`s look kinda weird inside complex boolean expression

Answer (score 0):

Multiple use of `select` is superfluous in this situation. You can use `&&` and `||` logical operators:

```
transactions.select do |transaction| 
  (@currency.nil? || transaction.currency == @currency) &&
  (@geo.nil? || transaction.geo == @geo) &&
  (@industry.nil? || transaction.industry == @industry)
end
```